# What does a Authorization Code contains?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, authorization

Authorization code flow - User logs in from client app, authorization server returns an authorization code to the app. The app then exchanges the authorization code for access token.So, I want to know what is the content that authorization server sends as authorization code?I mean what code or signature does  a authorization code contains?

Comment: I think you are looking for this: [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.3)

Comment: That is not I am asking..For example if you take a JWT token it generally have three parts: a header, a payload, and a signature.  In the same way what authorization code have?I want in what format does a authorization code consists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorization Code in oAuth is explained in the RFC for oAuth, in section 1.3.1 called Authorization Code. See:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1

> The authorization code is obtained by using an authorization server as
> an intermediary between the client and resource owner.  Instead of
> requesting authorization directly from the resource owner, the client
> directs the resource owner to an authorization server (via its
> user-agent as defined in [RFC2616]), which in turn directs the
> resource owner back to the client with the authorization code.
>
> Before directing the resource owner back to the client with the
> authorization code, the authorization server authenticates the
> resource owner and obtains authorization.  Because the resource owner
> only authenticates with the authorization server, the resource owner's
> credentials are never shared with the client.
>
> The authorization code provides a few important security benefits,
> such as the ability to authenticate the client, as well as the
> transmission of the access token directly to the client without
> passing it through the resource owner's user-agent and potentially
> exposing it to others, including the resource owner.

It is explained in more details with block diagrams in section 4.1 Authorization Code Grant, and in section 10.5 Authorization Codes. See:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.5

Some relevant quotes from the documentation referenced above:

> The transmission of authorization codes SHOULD be made over a secure
> channel, and the client SHOULD require the use of TLS with its
> redirection URI if the URI identifies a network resource.  Since
> authorization codes are transmitted via user-agent redirections, they
> could potentially be disclosed through user-agent history and HTTP
> referrer headers.
>
> Authorization codes operate as plaintext bearer credentials, used to
> verify that the resource owner who granted authorization at the
> authorization server is the same resource owner returning to the
> client to complete the process.  Therefore, if the client relies on
> the authorization code for its own resource owner authentication, the
> client redirection endpoint MUST require the use of TLS.
>
> Authorization codes MUST be short lived and single-use.  If the
> authorization server observes multiple attempts to exchange an
> authorization code for an access token, the authorization server
> SHOULD attempt to revoke all access tokens already granted based on
> the compromised authorization code.
>
> If the client can be authenticated, the authorization servers MUST
> authenticate the client and ensure that the authorization code was
> issued to the same client.

See the rest of RFC 6749 for more details:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749